# How to pass data from one Lifecycle hook to another

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am creating a service to get the data in ngAfterViewInit once it is done it.

```
export class AppComponent {     
    gameData:any;
    constructor(private _AppComponentService: AppComponentService) {}

    ngOnInit(){
        this._AppComponentService.getGameData().subscribe(x => {
            this.gameData = x;
        });
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this.gameData); //Undefined
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely because gameData is not ready yet. If you need gameData in afterViewInit function, you can move you service call to that function.

Comment: If I move the call in afterviewinit, It is still undefined.

Comment: @fruitjs if you console.log outside of subscribe of course you will still get undefined since getGameData() is an async function. Can you show how are you using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `.getGameData()` is probably some asynchronous call then when `ngAfterViewInit` is called the `this.gameData` property has no value because the callback for `.subscribe()` hasn't been called yet.

If you want to use Observables for this you can to make `gameData` a [`ReplaySubject`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/replaysubject.md) or subscribe to `.getGameData()` in both livecycle hooks:

1. Making `gameData` a `ReplaySubject`

   ```
   export class AppComponent {     
       gameData: ReplaySubject = new ReplaySubject(1);
       constructor(private _AppComponentService: AppComponentService) {}

       ngOnInit(){
           this._AppComponentService.getGameData().subscribe(x => {
               this.gameData.next(x);
           });
       }

       ngAfterViewInit() {
           this.gameData.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
       }
   }
   ```

With `ReplaySubject` the `ngAfterViewInit()` will receive a value even if it subscribes after `this.gameData.next(x)` emitted the value.

2. Subscribing to `.getGameData()` twice:

   ```
   export class AppComponent {     
       observable: Observable; // or EventEmitter depending on what you used in getGameData()
       constructor(private _AppComponentService: AppComponentService) {}

       ngOnInit(){
           this.observable = this._AppComponentService.getGameData();
           this.observable.subscribe(x => {
               // whatever you need
           });
       }

       ngAfterViewInit() {
           this.observable.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks martin for the help.